# One Domain, two web applications

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a web application hosted at example.com, for example.

I want to let the business have a wordpress blog, but for business reasons, it must be on a separate webserver. Yet, I'd like to have it visible at example.com/blog/

So, I'd like to have example.com be one application on one server environment, and /blog/ be a separate webserver.

We are running LAMP, and I don't know the best way to pull this off.  Any suggestions, or pointers to documentation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, port 80 is already used by apache, but you have a few choices:

- put a loadbalancer software (like haproxy) in front and let it listen on port 80, put two apache webservers behind (e.g. on port 81, 82) it and loadbalance /blog/ to webserver one, the rest to webserver two.
- use a different domain and use virtual hosts
- use mod_proxy from apache and redirect /blog/ to a different webserver transparently

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way is to create blog.example.com and have different DNS record for www.example.com and blog.example.com.

Comment: FYI, my solution is more reliable because there is no SPOF. The DNS balancing relies on the DNS architecture (primary and secondary/ies + cache), and does not require dedicated hosting. This is why I found it an interesting alternative to `/blog`.